# Laravel 5.1 .htaccess not working (pretty url's)

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5.1

So I have tried both versions of the .htaccess, the one that comes with it in project creation and the one in the documentation. I am currently using the one in the documentation:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I have my virtualhost set up like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
        ServerAdmin <my email>
        ServerName projectflyer.<my domain>.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projects/project-flyer/public
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I go to projectflyer.mydomain.com/some/route I get back a 404. Any ideas? Yes I can go to the base url just fine.

Comment: Could you please try adding `<Directory "/var/www/html/projects/project-flyer/public">Options Indexes FollowSymlinks AllowOverride All </Directory>` to your virtualhost configuration file.

Comment: actually figured this out and put that as an answer. Just about 30 seconds too late. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding this to my virtualhost .conf file:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/install/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thanks to http://laravel.io/forum/09-15-2015-removing-indexphp-from-url-laravel-5116 for the answer